# Removing leading zeros from sql with rules already applied

Tags: sql, string

I have had problems with outputting a string to the correct length of characters although with my basic sql knowledge I have been able to output to the correct length now by applying rules.  The next problem is that the coding structure sometimes outputs a `000000NA` string, but the software the output file is imported in to does not like the leading zeros and can only read it if its `NA`.

Is there commands to either:

remove the leading zeros so that the output is `NA` with no leading zeros
or
convert to `NA` when it reads `000000NA`

This is the part of the code that I need support with

```
, [Analysis code]       = '"' + ISNULL(RIGHT(AX.NominalCode, 8), '') + '"'
```

As you can see I've already adjusted to ensure it outputs the correct string length for report but now I need to add to this to ensure the zeros are removed when 000000NA is returned

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add a tag to specify what dialect of SQL you're working with.  `RIGHT`, for example, doesn't exist in the Oracle SQL dialect.  In the Oracle SQL dialect, you can `trim(leading '0' from <<string>>)` but that probably doesn't work in whatever dialect of SQL you're using.

Comment: The dialect of SQL you're using would generally depend on the database you're connecting to.  If you're building a SQL statement that is meant to run on a SQL Server database, for example, you're using SQL Server's dialect of SQL.  Note that some BI tools have their own dialect of SQL that they then convert to the dialect of whatever database they're connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the use of `ISNULL`, I'll assume you're working with Microsoft SQL Server.

One way to achieve the output you want would be with a [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```sql
,[Analysis code] = '"' + ISNULL(RIGHT(CASE
                                        WHEN AX.NominalCode = '000000NA' THEN 'NA'
                                        ELSE AX.NominalCode
                                      END, 8), '') + '"'
```

This will have the effect of substituting the value 'NA' for the value '000000NA' when that value is returned, but otherwise sending through the unmodified value of the column `AX.NominalCode`, trimmed to 8 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Ive just amended the script and for some reason its just output the string exactly the same again and as 000000NA despite the code making logical sense it would be output as NA.  Is there any other factors which would cause this not to work and output as intended?

Comment: That would indicate that AX.NominalCode is not, in fact, equal to '000000NA'. There are non-printing characters, or something else, that cause `AX.NominalCode = '000000NA'` to be false. What's the value of `DATALENGTH(AX.NominalCode)` when it returns that string?